# Java - Access to variabe in other file

Tags: java

I have ArrayList and protected getter function in first class and function in second class, which extends first class. I do `getList().size()` in function, but getting 0. If I do `myList.size()` in first class, I getting right answer.

Code:

`protected List<WrappedGameProfile> getList(){

    return Text;

}`

`public int getServerInfoSize(){

return super.getList().size();  //returns 0

}`

All code:

package ServerInfo;

//imports

public class ServerInfo extends JavaPlugin {

```
Logger log;
private List<WrappedGameProfile> Text = new ArrayList<WrappedGameProfile>();
FileConfiguration config;

protected String ConvertFormat(String format){
    return format.replace("#0", ""+ChatColor.BLACK).replace("#1", ""+ChatColor.DARK_BLUE).replace("#2", ""+ChatColor.DARK_GREEN).replace("#3", ""+ChatColor.DARK_AQUA).replace("#4", ""+ChatColor.DARK_RED).replace("#5", ""+ChatColor.DARK_PURPLE).replace("#6", ""+ChatColor.GOLD).replace("#7", ""+ChatColor.GRAY).replace("#8", ""+ChatColor.DARK_GRAY).replace("#9", ""+ChatColor.BLUE).replace("#a", ""+ChatColor.GREEN).replace("#b", ""+ChatColor.AQUA).replace("#c", ""+ChatColor.RED).replace("#d", ""+ChatColor.LIGHT_PURPLE).replace("#e", ""+ChatColor.YELLOW).replace("#f", ""+ChatColor.WHITE);
}

protected List<WrappedGameProfile> getList(){
    return Text;
}

protected void setText(List<WrappedGameProfile> Text){
    this.Text = Text;
}

public void onEnable(){
    log = getLogger();
    log.info("GuiServerInfo activating...");
    this.saveDefaultConfig();
    config = getConfig();
    ProtocolLibrary.getProtocolManager().addPacketListener(
        new PacketAdapter(this, ListenerPriority.NORMAL,
        Arrays.asList(PacketType.Status.Server.OUT_SERVER_INFO), ListenerOptions.ASYNC) {
            @Override
            public void onPacketSending(PacketEvent event) {
                handlePing(event.getPacket().getServerPings().read(0));
            }
        }
    );
    for (int i = 0; i < config.getStringList("Text").size();i++){
        Text.add(
                new WrappedGameProfile(
                        "id" + i + 1,
                        ConvertFormat(config.getStringList("Text").get(i)))
                );
        }
    log.info("GuiServerInfo active!");
}

@Override
public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command command, String label, String[] args) {
    if (sender.isOp()){
        if (args.length > 0){
            if (args[0].equalsIgnoreCase("set")){
                Text.clear();
                List<String> newConf = new ArrayList<String>();
                for (int i = 1; i < args.length; i++){
                    Text.add(new WrappedGameProfile("id" + Text.size() + 1, ConvertFormat(args[i])));
                    newConf.add(args[i]);
                    log.info("Add ServerInfo: " + args[i]);
                }
                config.set("Text", newConf);
                sender.sendMessage("Successful!");
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    } else {
        sender.sendMessage("You not op!");
        return true;
    }
}

private void handlePing(WrappedServerPing ping) {
    ping.setPlayers(Text);
}

public void onDisable(){
    saveConfig();
    log.info("GuiServerInfo disabled!");
}}
```

And:

package ServerInfo;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import com.comphenix.protocol.wrappers.WrappedGameProfile;

public class ServerInfoAPI extends ServerInfo {

```
public void setServerInfo(List<WrappedGameProfile> Text){
    super.setText(Text);
    super.log.info("Set new ServerInfo");
}

public void setServerInfo(String[] Text){
    List<WrappedGameProfile> tmp = new ArrayList<WrappedGameProfile>();
    for (int i = 0; i < Text.length; i++) {
        tmp.set(i, new WrappedGameProfile("id" + i + 1, ConvertFormat(Text[i])));
    }
    super.setText(tmp);
    super.log.info("Set new ServerInfo");
}

public void insertServerInfoString(String str, int num){
    getList().set(num, new WrappedGameProfile("id" + num, ConvertFormat(str)));
    super.log.info("Add new ServerInfo - num:" + num + ", Text:" + str);
}

public void addServerInfoString(String str){
    super.getList().add(new WrappedGameProfile("id" + super.getList().size() + 1, ConvertFormat(str)));
    super.log.info("Add new ServerInfo: " + str);
}

public int getServerInfoSize(){
    return super.getList().size();
}

public String getServerInfoString(int num){
    return super.getList().get(num).getName();
}

public int getServerInfoStringNum(WrappedGameProfile pr){
    return super.getList().indexOf(pr);
}
```

}

Comment: You shouldn't be talking in terms of files. You should be talking in terms of packages and classes.

Comment: Most likely you have two different objects and so you are not looking at the same ArrayList.

Comment: Okay, in other class.

Comment: No, i have just one List.

Comment: If the second _class_ extends the first _class_ like you said, then because you used the `protected` access modifier, it will be able to access the variable `Text`. Unless, of course, you created another variable with the same name in the second _class_. If you only created the list (the first line of code you showed) and then ran `getServerInfoSize()`, it will return `0` because the list contains no elements. Also, you might want to read up on inheritance in Java.

Comment: @chillworld No, i didn't do it. Maybe later.

Comment: no problem, can you post your start class where you call all this? cause your fault is there.

Answer (score 4):

Just your terminology alone shows a serious lack of understanding of things like Objects, Classes, Packages, etc. you need to read up on some introductory tutorials.

To answer the question it sounds like you have created a new instance inheriting from a super class. Because it is a new instance the list is not shared, so changes you make in one class do not get seen.

To share one list between multiple objects you need to pass the list object from one to another.

Comment: +1 for "serious lack of understanding" - cutting right to the heart of the problem drawing conclusions based on language choice.  Brilliant.

Comment: Good response, its like he is asking how to perform a drift turn without being able to recognize a car.

Comment: No, I didn't. Let me explain. I have first main class and second API class, which extends first class. It doesn't create any instances, just reading List in superclass.

Comment: Post the relevant code from both classes (where you create the variable, where you access it, where you print it, where you create the instance...but not everything if it is massive files) and I can be more specific.

Comment: @serega6531: Please let us explain again, you don't understand that by using inheritance, you **are** creating another instance of the variables. 1+ to this answer.

Comment: You can see my attempts in comments lower.

Comment: Edit your original question. Remove any code from the two classes that isn't relevant to the question. Post the remaining code into the original question. Don't forget to indent it by 4 spaces so that it gets formatted properly.

Comment: But you didn't put what I asked for. You only put a tiny bit of code there.

Answer (score 2):

Don't try to globalize variables. Instead call public methods of the class that holds the variable that will allow other objects to query its state or make *controlled* change to its state.

I agree also with the others: it sounds as if you're misusing inheritance, since this is not a problem that should be solved with inheritance, but only your code (which we haven't seen at the time of this writing) will tell us for sure.

Regarding:

> No, i have just one List

No, if you're using inheritance, then you have more than one List. Again don't try to solve this with inheritance.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you have a

```
private List<WrappedGameProfile> text =  new ArrayList<WrappedGameProfile>();

public List<WrappedGameProfile> getText() {
    return text;
}
```

in your super class?
than your code will be :

```
public int getServerInfoSize(){ 
    return getText().size();
}
```

and please do camelcasing correct, the variable Text has to be text.

Comment: Yes!! Java reserves capital letters for things like class names. Check [this](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-135099.html#367) link out for more.

Comment: Okay, wait a second...

Comment: Now i have:

`protected List<WrappedGameProfile> getList(){
  return Text;
 }`
And:


 `public int getServerInfoSize(){
  return super.getList().size();
 }`

And it's not working.

Comment: The classes there you called this, do you create a new object of that class cause then its normal you get 0. Or better, show is your main code that calls this